# WP All Import Pro: Polylang compatibility

Tags: wordpress, import, polylang, wpallimport

I'm trying to import data from an Excel sheet into WordPress with the Pro version of WP All Import. We are using Polylang for multi language support. I wonder how to manage importing the content into the correct language versions. I discovered that there is a hidden taxonomy "language" which I can manually set to "de" for setting language to German. But how do I link corresponding translations? Any ideas how to solve this, maybe with some custom functions? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I have found a better solution.

```
if ( !function_exists( 'pll_save_post_translations' ) ) {
require_once '/include/api.php'; }
$arr = array();
$result = pll_save_post_translations(['en' => 21398, 'ro'=>21396]);
```

//where 21398 and 21396 are the post_id and 'en' and 'ro' the nicenames of the languages.

Put this code in your functions.php and run it only once (meaning you refresh the page only once as admin after you put it). Then delete the code from functions.php. It does not actually create errors, just don't risk it, don't run it twice.

Before you do that, you must import the products in both (in my case) languages. Meaning you import them in one language (you select one language from the top admin bar) and then in another session you import them in the other language (you select the other language) and also if you see "Show private taxonomies" in WP All import, put one language code there. One for each session. After the products in both languages have been imported, you run the code above to tell WordPress that "this post_id is the translation of that post_id".
I hope it helps.
Ah, and you get the post_id in a nice table which you can edit in excel by exporting the products with Wordpress Export (it is pre-installed when you install WordPress, I think). You find it in Dashboard in Tools/Export.

And put
$result = pll_save_post_translations(['en' => 56465, 'ro'=>654864]);
as many times as you need

$result = pll_save_post_translations(['en' => 9999, 'ro'=>34654]);
$result = pll_save_post_translations(['en' => 98641, 'ro'=>98651]);  .

for each correlation.
You can do it easier in Excel, you have the correlating id's on two separate columns then put this formula on the next row
=concatenate("$result = pll_save_post_translations(['en' =>",CELL A1,"
'ro'=>",CELL B1,"]);")
Apply it downwards. Select the column you have just concatenated. Paste it under the code in functions.php. Save. Refresh. Delete code from functions.php. Refresh. Booyah.

Answer (score -1):

Please note that I'm currently using both Polylang and Wp All Import/Export Pro versions.

Also, **this is currently not 'outdated' code**. It relies on an undocumented feature, that was suggested directly from the wp all import team. I'm speaking simply of the additional parameter `$data` passed by the `pmxi_saved_post` action.

That said, I know polylang devs are currently working on an addon for this specific issue. Anyway, I managed to do it in this way, for now:

1 -> when you export data, there are 2 polylang-related fields: `languages` and `post_translations`. Export them too.

2 -> when you import your data, on the wpallimport screen, create 2 more custom fields and save the 2 above. See attachment below. Now you've got the translations data with every post.

3 -> set this filter:

```
global $language_codes;

$language_codes = array( // sample lang data
  'italiano' => 'it'
  ,'english' => 'en'
  ,'espanol' => 'es'
  ,'francais' => 'fr'
  ,'deutsch' => 'de'
);

add_action('pmxi_saved_post', 'set_imports_lang', 10, 2);

// using undocumented param $data
// action firm is the following (in fact, it passes 3 params): do_action( 'pmxi_saved_post', $pid, $rootNodes[$i], $is_update );
function set_imports_lang($post_id, $data){
  global $language_codes;
  // 'lingue' is italian, I guess it will be 'languages' in english: it's one of the 2 fields we saved before
  pll_set_post_language($post_id, $language_codes[sanitize_title($data->lingue)]);
}
```

At this point you have just set each post's original language, nothing more. Now we have to link translations each other. We'll do this with a function that we have to run ONLY 1 TIME. It will run simply reloading any wp screen/page.

```
function set_imports_translations(){
  global $wpdb;
  global $language_codes;

  // substitute 'enews' with your own post type
  $list = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT
      m.post_id, m.meta_value pll, group_concat(concat_ws(':', m2.meta_value, m.post_id)) ids
    FROM
      $wpdb->posts p
      INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta m ON p.ID = m.post_id
      INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta m2 ON m.post_id = m2.post_id AND m2.meta_key = '_import_language_name'
    WHERE
      p.post_type = 'enews' AND m.meta_key = '_import_translations_id'
    GROUP BY pll
  ");

  // query results are something like this:
  // 10258 pll_57e92254c445f 10258:Italiano,10259:English,10260:Español,10261:Français,10262:Deutsch
  // 10263 pll_57e922552b8c6 10263:Italiano,10264:English,10265:Español,10266:Deutsch
  // 10267 pll_57e9225587124 10267:Italiano


  // extract data from the third column string
  foreach($list as $item){
    $ids = explode(',',$item->ids);
    $list = array();

    foreach($ids as $id){
      $data = explode(':',$id);
      $list[$language_codes[sanitize_title($data[0])]] = intval($data[1]);
    }

    //set the translations
    pll_save_post_translations($list);
  }
}

set_imports_translations();
```

That's all. :) Ah, the attachment mentioned above:

[image]

Comment: Molto grazie! The set_imports_translations function saved countless hours. Note: exporting and then importing "languages" as a custom field worked fine with Polyang, without the need for the set_imports_lang function.

Comment: Hi Luca,

Can you elaborate on what "At this point you have just set each post's original language, nothing more" means?

I am confused what that means and when you do that. Do you do this after exporting and before importing? Is this all party of the last step to run "set_imports_transaltions ?

Comment: @Nick, that is done during import, with pmxi_saved_post filter. Maybe it's also documented in wp all import pro docs.

Keep in mind though, that you can ask polylang pro devs (via email) to give you access to their plugin for wp all import. They will and it works pretty well even if in beta. It's not very intuitive (I suggest you to do several configuration tests on few records until you reach the perfet one), but its ok even if beta.