# How to export Wordpress posts database tables with polylang?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, polylang

My current site is outdated (not updated for a long time), so created WordPress with all updated plugins, etc. I am using Polylang on my website for the language switching (English = Arabic), and I need to export all my posts in English and Arabic to my newly created WordPress website.

I tried to export/import with the default that comes with WordPress, but they don't map the language posts and I don’t want to remap the English to Arabic pages/posts as they are around 2500+ items.

If I can do the export /import from the database side, which all tables to be exported so I don't miss out on the Polylang translation strings and mappings.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a few tables that seem to be used by Polylang plugin

wp_terms (contains pll_)
wp_term_taxonomy (contains post_translations)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

https://wpsheeteditor.com/polylang-import-translations-quickly/

[WP All Import Pro: Polylang compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50909485/wp-all-import-pro-polylang-compatibility)

Comment: But I don't want to use extra plugins and don't want to add expenses to the project